# How to deploy qml application for winrt

Tags: qml, qt5, qt5.4

I am using Qt 5.4. I am getting error:

```
QML Image:host not fount
```

i use web-image source in Canvas.

some code as below:

```
import QtQuick 2.3

Canvas{
    id: canvas;

    property string icon: "http://static.moinmo.in/logos/moinmoin.png"

    Component.onCompleted: {
        loadImage(icon);
    }

    onImageLoaded: {
        bLoaded = true;

        requestPaint();
    }
}
```

But if i run in desktop. it works well

i want to know how to deploy the qml application for WinRT and windows phone. Thank you.

Comment: Please, show your code, at least the place when you initialize the `Image`

Comment: @folibis i had update it, thank you.

Comment: Do you get errors or you don't know from where to start to deploy to WinPhone?

Comment: Try to load image from recource or local file to make sure the problem is not in image plugin. Try to load something from http with other components, for example `WebView` to see if you have no network problem. Check application permissions or maybe logs (not sure Windows has some logs :) )

Comment: @folibis you are right, thank you. i don't have set the permissions (internetClient)